# login logout menu changes in wordpress

Tags: menus, login, logout

I am new to wordpress ,i use login and logout in my site,i already create pages for login , logout and register ,i wants to create 2 menu in navigation bar . one for register and another one for login and logout , before login 2 menus(login and register ) should visible and after login 1 menu(logout ) should visible,how can i make this possible,Please any one help me , without using plugin

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. may you please elaborate more?

Answer (score 1):

First: Your question does not indicate that you have made any programming attempt to get this done.

Code to do this....

```
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
// your 'entire-menu code' or 'logout' link for logged in user 
} else {
// your 'Entire-menu code' or 'login / Register' links for logged out user 
}
```

Second: I am sure you don't know programming. So, use this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/nav-menu-roles/